# Duplicate membership free basic plan in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I am working in rails application. The site provides for a membership with a basic free plan and a payment plan. in the console I entered: bundle exec rails console. At the command prompt I entered: Plan.create(name: 'basic', price: 0) and this created this free basic membership plan with an id=1

I then proceeded to enter: Plan.create(name: 'pro', price: 10) and this created the pro membership payment plan with an id=2

I did not concentrate and I accidentally entered: Plan.create(name: 'basic', price: 0) and this created this free basic membership plan with an id=3. Now I have two(2) basic free membership plans in the database when I should only have one (1)free basic plan and one(1) pro plan.

How can this third (3rd) basic free plan with id=3 be deleted from the database? I am still a student and not so conversant with web development at this time and any expert advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

From the rails console simply do `Plan.find(3).destroy` to remove that record.

You should then read up on validations so this situation doesn't happen again. For example in your Plan model have a validation to check that name is unique:

```
validate_uniqueness_of :name
```

Comment: Thanks David, I applied your instruction and it worked, the record is deleted.The problem is now solved.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. You might want to consider accepting solutions if they answer your questions :)

Comment: I am new to this, I will most gladly accept solutions if it answers my questions, but how is this done?

Comment: There is a greyed out tick under the vote up / vote down arrows for each answer to your question ... click on one to accept that answer as a solution to your problem ... use the arrows to vote up or down an answer if you feel the answer is particularly good or bad. You probably can't use the vote up/down though till you have more rep (15 i think)